# Malloc and bus 10 runtime error help C

Tags: c, malloc, free

So I have a specific programming assignment I am working on that I believe requires the use of the `malloc()` function with which I am unfamiliar. My understanding is if you use `malloc()` you must free the memory when you are done using it or you can end up with weird behavior. I'm wondering if that is why I'm getting a bus 10 runtime error every once in awhile?

The assignment is to write a rock scissors paper game and this is what I came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>      
#include <string.h>

char* getUserChoice() 
{
    /* Prompt the user "Enter rock, paper, or scissors: " and return
       the string they enter */
    printf("Enter rock, paper, or scissors: ");
    char * uChoice = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    scanf("%s", uChoice);
    return uChoice;
}

char* getComputerChoice() 
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    /* get a pseudo-random integer between 0 and 2 (inclusive) */
    int randChoice = rand() % 3;
    char * cpuChoice = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    /* If randChoice is 0, return "rock", otherwise if randChoice is 1, 
       return "paper", and if randChoice is 2, return "scissors". */
    if (randChoice == 0)
        cpuChoice = "rock";
    else if (randChoice == 1)
        cpuChoice = "paper";
    else
        cpuChoice = "scissors";
    return cpuChoice;
}

char* compare(char* choice1, char* choice2) 
{
    /* Implement the logic of the game here. If choice1 and choice2
    are equal, the result should be "This game is a tie."
    Make sure to use strcmp for string comparison.*/

    char * cmpChoice = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    int comparedValue = strcmp(choice1,choice2);
    if (comparedValue == 0)
        cmpChoice = "This game is a tie.";        
    else
    {
        if ((strcmp(choice1, "rock") == 0 && strcmp(choice2, "paper") == 0) || 
            (strcmp(choice1,"paper") == 0 && strcmp(choice2, "scissors") == 0) || 
            (strcmp(choice1, "scissors") == 0 && strcmp(choice2, "rock") == 0))
          cmpChoice = strcat(choice2, " wins");
        else
            strcat(choice1, " wins);
    }
    return cmpChoice;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char *userChoice, *computerChoice, *outcome;

    userChoice = getUserChoice();
    computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    outcome = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

    printf("You picked %s.\n", userChoice);
    printf("Computer picked %s\n", computerChoice);
    printf("%s\n", outcome);
    return 0;
}
```

The weird behavior I'm describing is sometimes the output will be like this

```
Enter rock, paper, or scissors: paper
You picked paper wins..       // why is it saying "You picked paper wins.."
Computer picked rock
paper wins.
```

and other times without any recompiling it will be

```
Enter rock, paper, or scissors: scissors
Bus error: 10 // possibly due to not calling free()?
```

If someone could help me understand how I would free the memory I allocated before I return the pointers that would be great. Obviously this would be much easier to just use strings but it is a requirement to use the `char *` type.

Thanks for any and all help or insight provided.

**EDIT with updated code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>      
#include <string.h>

char* getUserChoice() 
{
    /* Prompt the user "Enter rock, paper, or scissors: " and return
       the string they enter */
    printf("Enter rock, paper, or scissors: ");
    char * uChoice = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    scanf("%s", uChoice);
    return uChoice;
}

char* getComputerChoice() 
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    /* get a pseudo-random integer between 0 and 2 (inclusive) */
    int randChoice = rand() % 3;
    char * cpuChoice = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    /* If randChoice is 0, return "rock", otherwise if randChoice is 1, 
       return "paper", and if randChoice is 2, return "scissors". */
    if (randChoice == 0)
        strcpy(cpuChoice, "rock");
    else if (randChoice == 1)
        strcpy(cpuChoice, "paper");
    else
        strcpy(cpuChoice, "scissors");
    return cpuChoice;
}

char* compare(char* choice1, char* choice2) 
{
    /* Implement the logic of the game here. If choice1 and choice2
    are equal, the result should be "This game is a tie."
    Make sure to use strcmp for string comparison.*/

    char * cmpChoice = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    int comparedValue = strcmp(choice1,choice2);
    if (comparedValue == 0)
        strcpy(cmpChoice, "This game is a tie.");        
    else
    {
        if ((strcmp(choice1, "rock") == 0 && strcmp(choice2, "paper") == 0) || 
            (strcmp(choice1,"paper") == 0 && strcmp(choice2, "scissors") == 0) || 
            (strcmp(choice1, "scissors") == 0 && strcmp(choice2, "rock") == 0))
        {
            strcat(cmpChoice, choice2);
            strcat(cmpChoice, " wins");
        }
        else
        {          
            strcat(cmpChoice, choice1);
            strcat(cmpChoice, " wins.");
        }
    }
    return cmpChoice;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char *userChoice, *computerChoice, *outcome;

    userChoice = getUserChoice();
    computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    outcome = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);

    printf("You picked %s.\n", userChoice);
    printf("Computer picked %s\n", computerChoice);
    printf("%s\n", outcome);
    return 0;
}
```

So, thanks so much for everyones comments. I've fixed some spots on the code and it seems to be compiling and running without error. Now, I'm trying to figure out when to `free()` the malloced memory. I obviously can't free it after the return but I need to return the value.

Would I copy it to a `char` and then free the original memory allocated?

Thanks again

Comment: `cpuChoice = "foo";`, memory leak. Use strcpy or something like that for your malloced space. And you strcat your string in getComputerChoice(), so you get **win** in your first result. And if computer wins, you are doing strcat to string literal, so seg fault.

Comment: Can you expand more about the strcat string literal thing? I think this is the main issue with the program as I took that out and I'm not getting the bus error any longer.

Comment: [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) will modify content of **destination**, so you can't pass string literal as first parameter. Malloced space is OK, but you screw up in getComputerChoice().

Comment: Your statement cmpChoice = strcat(choice2, " wins.") modifies the string buffer that choice2 points to, and then changes the cmpChoice pointer to point to the same block of memory that choice2 already points to. You lose track of the memory cmpChoice originally pointed to. This runtime error is called a memory leak, and it's really hard to diagnose.

I think what you probably intended was to strncpy either choice1 or choice2 into the cmpChoice string buffer, and then strncat the literal " wins." at the end of the cmpChoice string buffer.

Comment: To simply solve your problem: 1. printf their choice right after choice. 2. assign computer choice using strcpy() or strncpy().

Comment: In C you have to be careful about whether a char* is pointing to a string literal like "wins" or a string buffer like you allocate with malloc() or char[80]. String literals are supposed to be read-only.

Comment: What is this `strcopy` you speak of?

Comment: Man I can't type at all tonight good catch

Comment: @user2948847 **Don't** change the code in the original question except to fix unrelated typos. Changing it as you have, the posted code no longer exhibits the original problem and no longer has *anything* to do with the question in the title.

Comment: @WhozCraig easily fixed sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use malloc.  Just pass a char pointer to the method instead of returning one.

```
void getUserChoice(char * choice)
{
    /* Prompt the user "Enter rock, paper, or scissors: " and return
       the string they enter */
    printf("Enter rock, paper, or scissors: ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
}
```

Then use it like this inside of main...

```
char uChoice[128];
getUserChoice(uChoice);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, what you say makes total sense. The only issue is I can't alter the return types (needs to return a char *).

Comment: Then just return choice as well.  If you can't alter the signature of the method then I guess malloc is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

`You picked paper wins..       // why is it saying "You picked paper wins.."`
in `char* compare(char* choice1, char* choice2)`, you do strcat() to choice1 and choice2.
So the content of userChoice is modified before you printf it.

Also in `char* getComputerChoice()`, you should strcpy() or strncpy() to copy string to newly malloced space, not `=`, the later is assign string literal,  and that's why sometime you got Segmentation fault, because if computer wins, your program will try to strcat choice2, which is not allowed to string literal.

Answer (score 0):

though you should use free for malloc memory and yes the problem is here

if (randChoice == 0)

```
    cpuChoice = "rock"; //use strcpy(cpuChoice,"rock");

else if (randChoice == 1)
    cpuChoice = "paper"; // strcpy(cpuChoice,"paper");
else
    cpuChoice = "scissors"; // strcpy(cpuChoice,"scissors");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the game will be preferred to be played more than once every time u run. u can use a while loop u can take input from the user to continue or not use switch inside and so on. below i have included only while loop.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
       char *userChoice, *computerChoice, *outcome;
       while(1)
       { 
              userChoice = getUserChoice();
              printf("You picked %s.\n", userChoice);
              computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
              printf("Computer picked %s\n", computerChoice);
              outcome = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);



              printf("%s\n", outcome);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

In this situation your code calls malloc n number times and it will lead to unnecessary memory creation. eventually may crash your program if use a lot since u have not freed the memory.

so freeing memory is always beneficial and better way to code.

And for undefined behavior u r using the same userchoice pointer and concatenating with result in function

```
            char* compare(char* choice1, char* choice2)
```

to avoid this u can move your "printf("You picked %s.\n", userChoice)"
after "userChoice = getUserChoice();" as shown above int the code

and also use strcpy() for copying the string in the function char* getComputerChoice()